Need help with the Inverse Laplace transform
I'm trying to solve this inverse Laplace transform, but I can't seem to get the right answer.
Wolfram and other applications agree that the answer is: $ \sin(2t)-2t\cos(2t) $
$$f(x) = \mathcal {L}^{-1}\biggl\{\frac{16}{(s^2 + 4)^2}\biggl\}$$
I'm doing it with a transform table, what I'm trying to do is to decompose it so that I get something like $t*sin(2t)$ but i get:
$$\frac{4s}{(s^2 + 4)^2}$$
and from this step I don't know how to get rid of the $4s$ in the numerator, I got stuck here so I went to wolfram for the solution.
The $sin(2t)$ part is fine but how could I get the $2t*cos(2t)$ expression.

Are you doing this from scratch or using a table of transforms?

Can you show what you have done so far?

Convolution theorem:
$$\mathcal L(f(t)*f(t))=(\bar f(s))^2$$
Here
$$\bar f(s)=4/(s^2+4)$$
So
\begin{aligned}
f(t)=\mathcal{L}^{-1}(\bar{f}(s)) & =\mathcal{L}^{-1}\left(\frac{4}{s^2+4}\right) \\
& =\mathcal{L}^{-1}\left(\frac{4}{(s+2 \mathrm{i})(s-2 \mathrm{i})}\right) \\
& =\frac{1}{\mathrm{i}} \mathcal{L}^{-1}\left(\frac{1}{s-2 \mathrm{i}}-\frac{1}{s+2 \mathrm{i}}\right) \\
& =-\mathrm{i}\left(\mathrm{e}^{2 \mathrm{i} t}-\mathrm{e}^{-2 \mathrm{i} t}\right) \\
& =2 \sin 2 t
\end{aligned}
So
\begin{aligned}
\mathcal{L}^{-1}\left((\bar{f}(s))^2\right) & =f(t) * f(t) \\
& =\int_0^t 2 \sin 2 \tau \cdot 2 \sin 2(\tau-t) \mathrm{d} \tau \\
& =\left.\frac{1}{2}(4 \tau \cos 2 t+\sin 2(t-2 \tau))\right|_0 ^t \\
& =2 t \cos 2 t-\sin 2 t
\end{aligned}

The integral of the last step of convolution can be obtained according to the product to sum fomula. The calculation of the inverse Laplace transform of first-degree fraction can be obtained according to the frequency shifting property of Laplace transform and the Laplace transform of $1$.

what a clever way to use the convolution theorem, and thanks for the clarification on the last integral.
